# Restrict unregistered users from accessing the whole joomla site

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, acl, access

How to Restrict **unregistered users** from accessing any of the Joomla website?

Comment: Are you asking how to limit unregistered users to just the Home page or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: To all pages of my site

Answer (score 2):

As far as question goes:

1. There is option to disable the website in global configuration
2. Go to permissions page of the global configuration
3. Allow "registered" user group to "access site" when it's offline (allowed to admins only by default)

Comment: I do not want to offline the site

Comment: Is there a specific reason for it? I mean nobody will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Good grief, so much offered when so little is asked.

1. No, taking the site offline restricts access to all but Super Users.
2. Who cares why he wants to do it. He asked if it can be done.
3. Here's a simple way to restrict access. It is written for J2.5 but the idea remains the same. Set permissions to be restrictive.

Comment: Do you say that you can not allow 'regular' registered users to access 'offline' joomla website?